# Disable browser caching the page and javascript running in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Whenever we deploy an application and the client reviews the app, sometimes the javascript doesn't work (not totally). But when the browser is refreshed, the page works as intended.

I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the cache. Is there a way to disable caching of pages? I'm using Azure with .NET 4.0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to reliably stop caching of files and links in most browsers is to append a random number or time to the file. e.g.

```
http://www.domain.com/js/script.js?date=20120409120003
```

This will mean it is a new link each time the page is loaded and next time it goes to get the file it won't have it available in cache.

Comment: If you use continuous integration/assembly versions you could use the assembly version of your code instead of the date to prevent caching only for cases where it really matters.